# Is there another way to indicate the route of FOSJsRoutingBundle in a script tag?

Tags: symfony, bundle

I am using the  FOSJsRoutingBundle. I link files in a Twig template as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
```

But when using the bundle KnpSnappyBundle to generate pdf files, I need to indicate the previous routes absolutely. By using Symfony 2.3, I have changed as follows in the path using asset:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{app.request.scheme ~ '://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
```

The probem I have is that the other route gives me error with this bundle. Is there any other way to put it? I tried putting the same as in the above does not work and using `url` instead of `path` does not work.

This is the error that I have:

```
The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "Loading pages (1/6)
[> ] 0%
[======> ] 10%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
[=======> ] 13%
[==========> ] 18%
[==========================> ] 44%
[============================> ] 47%
[==============================> ] 50%
[==============================> ] 50%
[===========================================> ] 73%
[==============================================> ] 78%
[============================================================] 100%
Counting pages (2/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Resolving links (4/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
[> ] Preparing
[============================================================] Page 1 of 1
Done
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError
"stdout: ""
command: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/app/../vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --lowquality --page-size 'A4' --viewport-size '‘1024x768’' '/tmp/knp_snappy576ad837d24a82.40556276.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy576ad837d25009.94614572.pdf'.
```

This is the controller:

```
public function GenerarPdfFestivosAction()
{

    $this->render(sprintf('BackendBundle:Festivos:calendario.pdf.twig'));
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $inicio =$em->getRepository('BackendBundle:Centro')->findInicioCurso();
    $fin =$em->getRepository('BackendBundle:Centro')->findFinCurso();


    $html = $this->renderView('BackendBundle:Festivos:calendario.html.twig', array(
        'inicio' => $inicio,
        'fin' => $fin,
    ));

    return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'        => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="Calendario.pdf"'
        )
    );
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: what error? why do you need js routes to generate pdf?

Comment: Hello @SylvainGuilbert, I need to generate a route that contains a Twig template in another, to fill some data I need. Get the html, but to convert it to pdf with this bundle gives me error with the route as well. In this bundle you have to use absolute paths, but still continues mistake, I guess it will be for something `... / routing? Callback = fos.Router.setData` containing the route. The error I've added in the statement. In my case I add with `load` the contents of another template so: `$('container').load(Routing.generate('holidays_per_month', {id:month}));`

Comment: @SylvainGuilbert Do you know if there is any way to put `path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"})` otherwise? 
I do not really know for it that route, but maybe there is a more explicit indicate. I do not know if it has something to do with the route I want to generate('holidays_per_month').

Answer (score 0):

your pdf is generated and you can use it like so ([answer from here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/issues/177#issuecomment-148365508)):
In your controller :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;

    function generatePdfAction($param){
       $generator =  $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf');
       $pdf = null;
       $fileName = '/myDir/Calendario.pdf'; // change this
       $inicio =$em->getRepository('BackendBundle:Centro')->findInicioCurso();
       $fin =$em->getRepository('BackendBundle:Centro')->findFinCurso();
       $html = $this->renderView('BackendBundle:Festivos:calendario.html.twig', array(
                'inicio' => $inicio,
                'fin' => $fin,
               ));
       try {
            $pdf = $generator->getOutputFromHtml($html);
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $matches = [];
            if (preg_match('/([^\']+)\'.$/', $e->getMessage(), $matches)) {
                $pdf = file_get_contents($matches[1]);
                unlink($matches[1]);
            } else  {
                throw $e;
            }
        }
       if ($pdf){
          file_put_contents($fileName, $pdf);
          return new BinaryFileResponse($fileName);
       }
       else{
       // error message or smthing
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hello @SylvainGuilbert, sorry I'm new to this, where you would use this code? Without using the line that gives me problem I automatically goes to download the pdf and controller I have: `return new Response(
            $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
            200,
            array(
                'Content-Type'        => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="Calendario.pdf"'
            )
        );`

Comment: you put this in the controller function responsible for the pdf generation,

Comment: Thanks for your help @SylvainGuilbert. I've been testing the controller modifying that code and not get it to work. I added the driver you use in the statement, Can you tell how should I change it? (The variables `$inicio` and `$fin` displayed on the controller are need to pass data to the template).

Comment: Thanks  @SylvainGuilbert, Now I have the following error: `ContextErrorException: Warning: file_put_contents(/myDir/Calendario.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/......./FestivosController.php line 471` Corresponding to the line code `file_put_contents($fileName, $pdf);`

Comment: of course the $file is just an exemple you should put your pdf file in an existing directory

Comment: Hello @SylvainGuilbert, sorry for the ignorance  because I am new to all this How I can refer to the path of the download folder of the operating system?

Comment: just put the path eg : `/var/www/myfolder`

Comment: Look @SylvainGuilbert, I tried the route set and kept giving me the same error, and looking through the web I put this:`$basePath = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');` and `$fileName = $basePath.'/Calendario.pdf'; // change this`. with this shows me the pdf to download (although I do not want you to show me the pdf on the screen, only the prompt box to download what appeared before me).

Comment: Furthermore @SylvainGuilbert, the problem is that the PDF content without data obtained when generating the route of the other template with SOFJsRoutingBundle appears, so I think it is the error I mentioned in the statement regarding the bundle KnpSnappyBundle and path for SOFJsRoutingBundle.

Comment: ok I think I understand, you want to generate the page with some dynamic contents retrieved through ajax. Generation being server side I dont think it's possible

Comment: Okay @SylvainGuilbert, then I'll pass data from the controller and use the template and so I don't think I will give problems. Thanks for everything.